# Custom EditTextPreference. How and when to get text for saving purposes

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm writing custom EditTextPreference.

Using this code inside my CustomEditTextPreference:

```
@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean shouldSave) {
    if (shouldSave) {
        String sValue = getText();          
        value = Float.parseFloat(sValue);           
        peristValue();
    }
}
```

sValue is null. How do I acquire the value from edit then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use

```
getEditText().getText().toString();
```

Since [`getText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html#getEditText%28%29) by itself gets the current SharedPreference value, which may or may not exist.